# How to hide x.jar java classes visibility to others who are using my y.aar file?

Tags: jar, aar

y.aar includes x.jar file.
while giving y.aar to other developers they should not know this x.jar is included or cannot see the package.

In this y.aar file I am including that x.jar but want to hide internal jar or prevent importing those internal jar java classes

Comment: you could try to repackage `x.jar` with jarjar and then obfuscate your library with proguard

Comment: jarjar is not working. In jar I am having native dependency